# Speeding up rolling calculations within a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the index is a datetime, and it is sorted. Basically I want to creating a column rolling_time1, rolling_time2,... etc where the value is the number of count after the row that is within timex. I created the following but it is very slow. Any ways to make this faster?

```
def sum_window_wd(row, wd_file, wd, df, num):
    if row.start_index > num:
        return row['rolling_' + str(wd)]    
    count = 0
    for i in range(row.start_index + 1, len(df)):
        if GetWinddownLeft(wd_file, df.iloc[i].name, row.name) < wd:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            break
    return count

 for rolling in rollings:
     df['rolling_' + str(rolling)] = 0

for rolling in rollings:
     df['rolling_' + str(rolling)] = df.apply(sum_window_wd, axis=1, args = (winddown, rolling, df, len))
```

Comment: Did you try using [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas-dataframe-rolling)??

Comment: Right but I am actually basing it off of a customized time

Comment: The row times are NOT periodic?